# Can't get bxSlider PreloadImages=visible working

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, bxslider

I'm currently working with bxSlider and I'm trying to get the preLoadImages=visible functionality working. According to the website this should be on by default, but it seems like it's not doing anything.

My code is pretty basic:

```
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        preloadImages: 'visible'
    });
```

Yet it seems every time all the images are loaded at the same time. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. You may be wanting to hide all the images until loading is complete?

> bxslider has a callback when the slider is loaded (onSliderLoad).I set
>   visibility to hidden on a container div and then use the callback to
>   set the visibility to "visible."

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19501810/4842208