# jQuery load element not working for ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to preload ajax data before attaching it to a div and for that I have this code:

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: 'ajax.php',
   data: { modelID:id },
   type: 'post',
   success: function(result){

      $(result).load(function(){
         $('.view_'+id).html(result)
         $('.view_'+id).find('.brandModelGallery').bxSlider({})
         $('.view_'+id).addClass('loaded')
      })

   }
})
```

And this doesn't return anything. If write it as `$('.view_'+id).load(result)` then I can see all the contents of `result` in console as a syntax error so it fetches them alright, but not this way. Why is that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ I think you need to read the docs again about the `.load()` function

Comment: `load()` ajax method is different than `load()` method shorthand for `load` event

Comment: @Mivaweb in that case, how can I check if the data has loaded?

Comment: When it get to success function, the `result` is already loaded.

Comment: @Xeen Which data? `html()` is synchronous method so i'm really not sure to understand what you mean

Comment: @fuyushimoya then why do I get `bxSlider` images still loading after the content displays?

Comment: @Xeen Maybe bxSlider is forcing the reload of the images

Comment: @Xeen see e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658605/how-to-get-bxslider-to-hide-the-slides-until-the-page-loads

Comment: @Xeen Is your result is a string like `<div>xxx <img class="bxxx" src="yyy"></div>`?

Comment: @fuyushimoya yes, it's just like that

Answer (score 0):

I've create an example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qx8bjv4/7/)

Html:

```
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

js:

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: './',
   data: { modelID: '1' },
   type: 'post',
   success: function(result){
     console.log(result);
     $('#d1').html(JSON.stringify(result));
     // A fake object as your result.
       var bxSlider =  $('<ul class="bxslider"><li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/KsV6jS5.png" /></li><li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bqcK47I.png" /></li></ul>');       

       // Do thing only when all img loaded.
       var unLoadimges = bxSlider.find("img").length;
       bxSlider.find('img').load(function() {
           --unLoadimges;
           console.log("loaded, left: " + unLoadimges);
           if (unLoadimges === 0) {
               bxSlider.appendTo($("#d2")).bxSlider();
           }
       });
   }
})
```

When you append `img` element to your page, it doesn't mean its loaded. Listen to its `load` event.

Edit: Just make the bxSlider works on my example now.
Not sure if there's a better way to check whether all images loaded or not.